# Django, division between two annotate result won't calculate correctly

Tags: python, django, floating-point, annotate

I'm trying to get a division between two annotate results in queryset. Impression is much larger than click, so I should get tenth decimal.

```
def get_queryset(self):
        return googleData.objects.filter(account=self.account_name).\
            values('date').\
            annotate(Sum('click'), Sum('impression'), Sum('converted_click'),
                     Sum('conversion_value'), Sum('cost'), Sum('conversion_value'), ctr_monthly= Sum('click')/Sum('impression')).\
            order_by('-date')
```

Trouble here:

```
ctr_monthly= Sum('click')/Sum('impression'))
```

In template i have:

```
<td>{{ googleData.ctr_monthly | floatformat:2}} </td>
```

And the result is 0.00. 
If I do ctr_final = click * impression, it generates correctly.
Click & Impression are both integerfield.

I tried use the float(), gave me a syntax error.

**The other question is:** what's the best pratice to make a queryset like this? Is there any way that I can break it down to several short piece of code and make it more neat and readable ?

Thank you~

Answer (score 45, accepted):

With newer versions of Django, you can use the new `Func` object to cast the values to `FloatFields` or `DecimalFields` before the `Sum`.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import FloatField
ctr_monthly= Cast(Sum('click'), FloatField())/Cast(Sum('impression')), FloatField())
```

Even with an older version of Django, you might be able to just specify the `output_field` on the `Sum` before annotating ctr_monthly like so:

```
from django.db.models import F
def get_queryset(self):
    return googleData.objects.filter(
        account=self.account_name
    ).values('date').annotate(
        click_sum=Sum(
            'click',
            output_field=FloatField()
        ),
        impression_sum=Sum(
            'impression',
            output_field=FloatField()
        ),
        converted_click_sum=Sum('converted_click'),
        conversion_value_sum=Sum('conversion_value'),
        cost_sum=Sum('cost')
    ).annotate(
        ctr_monthly=F('click_sum') / F('impression_sum')
    ).order_by('-date')
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware, there isn't a way to do this using the ORM.

The `Sum()` function returns the same field type as put into it (i.e. an IntegerField() will always return an Integer). You could use a function like `ExpressionWrapper` to force the output to be a float, but that won't help in this case as it will be too late: the division of two integers will have been already returning another integer.

To solve your problem, remove the `ctr_monthly` section form your query, and create a simple template tag which converts the two numbers to floats and divide them.

Your template will then look like:
`<td>{{ monthly_ctr(googleData.click, googleData.impression) | floatformat:2}} </td>`

Comment: This works! Thank you. Is a a better practice to have everything in decimalField ?

Answer (score 1):

My case is a bit different but it will help you to solve your problem.
In my case I want `float` value for `percentage` but I got `integer` in response. So I use Cast to get `float` value for numerator which solved my problem.

```
return category_qs.annotate(
            rankings_count=Count(
                f"user_{self.category}_rankings__user", distinct=True
            ),
            percentage=Case(
                When(
                    rankings_count__gt=0,
                    then=Cast(F("rankings_count") * 100, FloatField())
                    / users_count,
                ),
                default=Value(0.0),
                output_field=FloatField(),
            ),
        ).order_by("-percentage")
```