# Django's annotate Count with division returns integer instead of float

Tags: django, django-orm, django-annotate

I have many objects and 3 of them have name='AAA'

I group them by 'name' and annotate num in group:

```
my_models = MyModel.objects.order_by('name').values('name').annotate(count=Count('name'))

for i in my_models:
    print(i.count, i.name)
```

I get:

```
3, 'AAA'
1, 'BBB'
...
```

Everything is fine, but when I try to add some formula to annotate Count():

```
my_models = MyModel.objects.order_by('name').values('name').annotate(count=Count('name') / 2)
```

I get:

```
1, 'AAA'
0, 'BBB'
...
```

But expected:

```
1.5, 'AAA'
0.5, 'BBB'
...
```

**EDIT:**

Python division differs from SQL division through Django's ORM, 
so 2/1 in python 3 returns 2.0 - OK, but not in SQL

Comment: How about `/ 2.0`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, python division and division from SQL differs :(

Comment: In Django 1.10 you can use `Cast`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40550677/113962). On Django 1.8+, you might be able to use [`ExpressionWrapper`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations).

Comment: @Alasdair big thx, man!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Full answer following [@Alasdair's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41091635/djangos-annotate-count-with-division-returns-integer-instead-of-float/41208263#comment69388742_41091635):

```
from django.db.models import FloatField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

qs = MyModel.objects.order_by('name').values('name').annotate(
    count=Cast(Count('name') / 2.0, FloatField()))
```

Comment: @rluts , try to cast both of variable first, example total=Cast(Count('id'), FloatField() / Cast(Count('id'), FloatField())

Comment: It isn't actually necessary to cast both - the way Python works is that if one of the values of an arithmetic expression is a float the result will be cast to float as well.